# Difference between return value through intent and processed value inside broadcast receiver onReceived method

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, android-broadcast

I am trying to make an android application which scans WiFi APs and send them to the server. I realized when I just toast the result inside onReceived method, scan results doesn't lag(which means getScanResult wait until it gets new scan results when scan button is cliched), but when I try to just toast it in onClicked method using intent bundle, it shows old results or doesn't refresh the results completely for first few times. I don't understand why. I am using same approach for both of them except the fact that I am passing the data through intent and bundle. Would you tell me why it happens and how I can fix this. Thank you.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Display List
    mAPListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.APListView);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw);
    mCalPrm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calPrm);
    //Buttons
    mRefreshButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);

    responseTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean wasGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(mLocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean wasNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(mLocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    boolean wasWiFiEnabled = mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled();

    if (!wasWiFiEnabled) {
        mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }

    IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
    i.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
        {
            mWifiList = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
            ArrayList mListOfProviders = new ArrayList<String>();
            Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = sortByComparator(mergeBSSID(mWifiList));
            Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = sortedMap.entrySet();
            int count = 0;
            JSONArray APs = new JSONArray();
            for (Map.Entry entry : entrySet) {
                if (count < 6) {
                    Object key = entry.getKey();
                    Object val = entry.getValue();
                    mListOfProviders.add(key + "  " + val + "dB"); //This will add the SSID of the connection
                    JSONObject AP = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        AP.put("BSSID", key);
                        AP.put("SS", val);
                        APs.put(AP);
                        count++;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, mListOfProviders);
            mAPListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("apArray", APs.toString());
            resultIntent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(resultIntent);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, APs.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    },i);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    } else {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    //check user's permission about location information
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method

    } else {
        //Scan wifi APs click event
        mRefreshButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


public void onClick(View view) {
    mWifiManager.startScan();
    JSONObject dataPackage = new JSONObject();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String APList = extras.getString("apArray");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, APList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }  
}
```

Comment: `mWifiManager.startScan();`. You could as well place that as last statement in onClick(). Does not make any difference. Do you understand why?

Comment: `Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);` That will create a new instance of MainActivity. (I suppose that all the posted code is part of MainActivity?).

Comment: in the `onClick(View view)` event : mWifiManager.startScan();` is an asynchronous operation and returns immediately. The `getIntent().getExtras();` method will get the previous results you placed into the bundle before you called `startActivity(resultIntent)` - so you will keep getting the previous results every time `onClick()` is called until the asynchronous task `startScan()` completes and creates a new `MainActivity` - I would not start a new MainActivity every time.

Comment: So where should I place startScan() in?

Comment: Firstly I would disable the `Button` (`myButton.setEnable(false);`) whilst a scan is taking place, and enable it again once the Broadcast for your `IntentFilter` calls `onReceive()` that way you ensure you only see one toast.  I'd redesign the structure so that you don't start a new Activity everytime 'onReceive()` is called, but to update the current Activity.

Comment: How would its new structure look like? I am very new to android development. I don't have enough understanding in android other than single methods. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MarkKeen So should I write mRefreshButton.setEnabled(false) under mWifiManager.startScan() and enable it inside onReceive method?